# Can I run native C++ binary on Azure?

Tags: c++, azure

I want to practice a bit with cloud and grpc so I thought about building a small binary(ISO C++, not managed or C++/CX) that runs on Azure.
I plan to use VS 2015 to do this.

Can I run native code on Azure?
I found no tutorials, and on SO I only found some outdated question.

Comment: Define what you mean by Azure in this case. Sure, you can get a full blown VM in Azure and run whatever you want there. But not sure what Azure service you're talking about.

Comment: If you can run .net there, I can't see a reason why you couldn't run any other native executable. The CLR itself is a C++ executable, after all.

Comment: @user3104201: Well, one hypothetical reason could be that Azure VM's have the CLR whitelisted, while your own binary would not be. But it appears there are quite a few Azure VM flavors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure offers different products. In case if you buy ordinary virtual 
machine - you can run whatever you want.

But, if we are talking about application services - it's clearly stated that "Build standards-based web apps and APIs using .NET, Java, Node.js, PHP, and Python." Quick googling shows us, that even Ruby is not supported, so, it's safe to assume that this is list is valid and native C++ apps are not working also.

Comment: This applies to one specific Azure product, which isn't the right product for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Azure offers a number of options to run your software. As Starl1ght mentioned, you can run ordinary VM's. There are about 8 other options. For instance, Azure Batch allows you to use compute nodes for batch processing:

> "Nodes can run any executable or script that is supported by the
>   operating system environment of the node. This includes *.exe, *.cmd,
>   *.bat and PowerShell scripts for Windows"
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics